# Provide preferences datastore with Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-datastore

I was trying to provide a common `DataStore<Preferences>` so that the same preference file could be used in multiple places but I got the helpful error message:

> Cannot find symbol: DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.builder()

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object DataStoreModule {
    
    @Provides
    fun provideDataStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> = context.createDataStore("settings")
}
```

I can however do the following and use it within an `@Inject` constructor.

```
@Singleton
class DataStoreProvider @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) {

    val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = context.createDataStore("settings")
}
```

I assume that the extension `createDataStore` is doing something that Hilt does not like but I'd appreciate an explanation of what is going on even if the problem is not solvable.

Comment: Please add your Gradle.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This worked for me:

```kotlin
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun dataStore(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): DataStore<Preferences> =
        appContext.createDataStore("settings")
```

The idea is to put `@Singleton` behind the provider method.

---

**Update on Feb 9, 2021:**
Preferably, create a [manager](https://github.com/Drjacky/MVVMTemplate/blob/master/presentation/src/main/kotlin/app/web/drjackycv/presentation/datastore/DataStoreManager.kt) and provide that:

```kotlin
class DataStoreManager(appContext: Context) {

    private val settingsDataStore = appContext.createDataStore("settings")

    suspend fun setThemeMode(mode: Int) {
        settingsDataStore.edit { settings ->
            settings[Settings.NIGHT_MODE] = mode
        }
    }

    val themeMode: Flow<Int> = settingsDataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[Settings.NIGHT_MODE] ?: AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED
    }

}
```

[AppModule](https://github.com/Drjacky/MVVMTemplate/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/app/web/drjackycv/mvvmtemplate/di/module/AppModule.kt):

```kotlin
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun dataStoreManager(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): DataStoreManager =
        DataStoreManager(appContext)
```

**Update on March 20, 2021:**
Version 1.0.0-alpha07

```kotlin
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("settings")

class DataStoreManager(appContext: Context) {

    private val settingsDataStore = appContext.dataStore

    suspend fun setThemeMode(mode: Int) {
        settingsDataStore.edit { settings ->
            settings[Settings.NIGHT_MODE] = mode
        }
    }

    val themeMode: Flow<Int> = settingsDataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[Settings.NIGHT_MODE] ?: AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED
    }
}
```

## Update on May 1, 2021:

@Florian is totally right, I had forgotten that.

Remove `dataStoreManager` provider from your DI module. Just:

```kotlin
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("settings")

@Singleton //You can ignore this annotation as return `datastore` from `preferencesDataStore` is singletone
class DataStoreManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) {

    private val settingsDataStore = appContext.dataStore

    suspend fun setThemeMode(mode: Int) {
        settingsDataStore.edit { settings ->
            settings[Settings.NIGHT_MODE] = mode
        }
    }

    val themeMode: Flow<Int> = settingsDataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[Settings.NIGHT_MODE] ?: AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED
    }

}
```

Comment: New release of DS removed Context.createDataStore extension function Use now: private val Context.settingsDataStore by preferencesDataStore("settings")

Comment: The manager should have an `@Inject` constructor instead of a `@Provides` method

Comment: This would be much easier to follow if you combined all of your updates into a single, cohesive answer.

Answer (score 24):

As Dr.jacky mention, create a manager is now recommended way, but you can still use `PreferenceDataStoreFactory` and create Preferences DataStore singleton:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun providePreferencesDataStore(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): DataStore<Preferences> =
    PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
        produceFile = {
            appContext.preferencesDataStoreFile(PREFERENCES_STORE_NAME)
        }
    )
```

Comment: This approach was also recommended in the datastore codelab by Google

Comment: @FlorianWalther Could you provide a link to that codelab?

Comment: Sorry, it was too long ago, I don't remember the codelab. I should've linked it right away :(

Comment: I just found an article about this on medium.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-dependency-injection-ea32b95704e3

Comment: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#0

Comment: `In a production application, the DataStore instance should be injected as a singleton in the classes that need it, by using DataStoreFactory...` https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#5  Accessed Jan 26, 2023

Answer (score 9):

I used `DataStore<Preferences>` with Hilt as following.

PersistenceModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object PersistenceModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDataStoreManager(@ApplicationContext context: Context): DataStoreManager {
        return DataStoreManager(context)
    }
}
```

DataStoreManager.kt

```
class DataStoreManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {

    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(STORE_NAME)

    private suspend fun <T> DataStore<Preferences>.getFromLocalStorage(
        PreferencesKey: Preferences.Key<T>, func: T.() -> Unit) {
        data.catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }.map {
            it[PreferencesKey]
        }.collect {
            it?.let { func.invoke(it as T) }
        }
    }

    suspend fun <T> storeValue(key: Preferences.Key<T>, value: T) {
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[key] = value
        }
    }

    suspend fun <T> readValue(key: Preferences.Key<T>, responseFunc: T.() -> Unit) {
        context.dataStore.getFromLocalStorage(key) {
            responseFunc.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataStore: DataStoreManager
) : LiveCoroutinesViewModel() {

    fun readNextReviewTime() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStore.readValue(nextReviewTime) {
                // Here you can do something with value.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
@HiltViewModel
class TranslateViewModel @Inject constructor(
    definitionRepository: DefinitionRepository,
    translateRepository: TranslateRepository,
    val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager
) : LiveCoroutinesViewModel() {

    init {
        readValueInViewModelScope(sourceLanguage, "ta") { // use value here }
        readValueInViewModelScope(targetLanguage, "si") { // use value here }
    }

    private fun <T> readValueInViewModelScope(key: Preferences.Key<T>, defaultValue: T, onCompleted: T.() -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreManager.readValue(key) {
                if (this == null) {
                    storeValueInViewModelScope(key, defaultValue)
                } else {
                    onCompleted.invoke(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun <T> storeValueInViewModelScope(key: Preferences.Key<T>, value: T) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreManager.storeValue(key, value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `@Provides` and `@Inject` for the `DataStoreManager`? One of them is enough.

Comment: func.invoke is not called if data not exists, and I can´t handle the response

Comment: Hi @dilanka-laksiri what is PersistenceModule for? how I can use it?

Comment: @ziniestro I use Hilt for DI. So `PersistenceModule` is a DI object.

Answer (score 3):

## Update on 2023

Read [DataStore and dependency injection](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-dependency-injection-ea32b95704e3) by [Simona Stojanovic](https://medium.com/@anomisSi)