# Proper instance creation of Android's Jetpack DataStore (alpha07 version)

Tags: android, android-studio, datastore, android-jetpack-datastore

So with the new alpha07 version, Android ditched the `private val dataStore = context.createDataStore(name = "settings_pref")`, however the new way they use datastore doesn't work for me.

Since upgrading from "androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0-alpha06" to alpha07, I can't seem to make my datastore syntax work without getting red-colored code (the error comes when i add context.dataStore.edit). Also downgrading back to alpha06, code that previously worked is now not working anymore (with createDataStore).

What I'm using is their example on the [main page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#typed-datastore) but going anywhere else they still haven't updated their examples besides this one.

```
@Singleton
 class PreferencesManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) {
    val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
    
      
        val EXAMPLE_COUNTER = intPreferencesKey("example_counter")
        val exampleCounterFlow: Flow<Int> = context.dataStore.data
            .map { preferences ->
                // No type safety.
                preferences[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] ?: 0
            }
    
        suspend fun incrementCounter() {
            context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
                val currentCounterValue = settings[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] ?: 0
                settings[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] = currentCounterValue + 1
            }
        }
    }
```

If someone knows the problem (or my error), I would appreciate it.

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: +1 Landed on this too right now, If anyone knows this problem, Attaching image for clarity @ianhanniballake https://prnt.sc/10cqim3

Comment: @ianhanniballake well basically what Abhishek-an showed, either context, dataStore or edit are shown as unresolved reference.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This was throwing me too, but I figured it out (aka, guessed until it worked):

```kotlin
// Note: This is at the top level of the file, outside of any classes.
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("user_preferences")

class UserPreferencesManager(context: Context) {
    private val dataStore = context.dataStore
    // ...
}
```

This is for a `DataStore<Preferences>`, but if you need a custom serializer, you can do the following (same parameters as the old method):

```kotlin
// Still top level!
private val Context.dataStore by dataStore(
    fileName = "user_preferences",
    serializer = MyCustomSerializer,
)
```

Comment: Yeah that's it, I figured it out too by guessing haha, I'll mark it as the right answer

Comment: @Alex Any idea how to instance it using Hilt?

Comment: @animusmind maybe try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66101769/15927514

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a mistake: Context should be as a member of class to use it in any method:

```
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("preferences")
class Preferenses(val context: Context) { get, set, etc}
```